# Name of the metric: $d(f,g)=\max \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

What is the name of the metric:

$$d(f,g)=\max \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$$

Where $f,g\in X$ where $X$ is the space of all continuous functions.

---

I can't find any documentation on this metric. Thanks.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the $L_\infty$ norm?

Comment: I think this is just the sup metric on compact spaces.

Comment: @Tyler I can't tell from the wikipedia page if this suggestion is correct. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Is it first of all a metric? Defining a metric as $\max$ you have a problem with the triangular inequality. It does not hold. So first of all we must check that the above is a metric. I can assure that $\min$ is.

Comment: @Tolaso - Sorry for late asking. I just saw it. Yes, it failed to be metric because triangular inequality doesn't hold in case of $\max$. And exactly, for the same reason faced in $\max$, it is not metric also if it is replaced by $\min$. How to do prove the triangular inequality holds for the case of $\min$?